# Xamarin.Ios Embed Video

Tags: ios, video, xamarin.ios

Good morning,

I have to embed a video from my resources in a UIView.
So in first I add my video to my resources folder and put his build action to "content".
My video is in MP4 format.

Then I created this func which is call in ViewDidLoad.

```
void Video()
{
string fileName = "Resources/Movies/menu.mp4";
string locallUrl = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);

    NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromFilename("menu.mp4");

    _player = new MPMoviePlayerController(url);
    _player.View.Frame = VideoView.Bounds;
    VideoView.AddSubview(_player.View);

    _player.ControlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;
    _player.PrepareToPlay();
}
```

And then I called _player.Play() in ViewDidAppear.

But nothing happen.

I think i missed something but I don't know what.

Thank's in advance,

Regards,

Anthony

Comment: you don't need to pass `Resources/` in fileName, try to add this it will work `Movies/menu.mp4`

Comment: check out this link https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/play_a_video_using_mpmovieplayercontroller/

Comment: It didn't work if I remove `Ressources/` from path. And I've already look at this link.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

The first one was MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated since iOS8. So I have to use AVPlayerViewController;

The second one is the creation of the NSUrl.
The right way is 
`NSUrl url = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("Movies/scroll", "mp4");`

The `Movies` folder is in `Resources` folder.